# W3C Markup Validation - Illegal character in PHP query: not a URL code point

Tags: html, w3c-validation

### What's the problem?

I am currently trying to validate my client's website, but cannot resolve the following issue.

> Bad value /php/captcha_code_file.php?rand= for attribute src on element img: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

The full line that the validator points to can be found below.

```html
<html>
<!-- ... -->
<img src="/php/xyz.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id="captchaimg" alt="captcha"><br/>
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

### What have I done?

It's my understanding that any spaces in URLs are to be replaced with `%20`, but I can't imagine that would be the problem inside the actual query - especially since I've tried this already and received the same error.

---

**Edit**:  My question is not about validating the PHP the `src` property is pointing to, but rather how the value/string is formatted for `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the validator the source code to a PHP program, when you should be giving it the HTML document you get when you run the PHP program.

It is a markup validator, not a PHP source code validator.

Comment: So the way I have the value of the `src` property is correct?  I'm not trying to validate the PHP it's pointing to, just the way the HTML shown above is formatted.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you're saying.  Could I remove the php section of the URL and replace it with something else?  Or would that be considered forgery, and thus false validation?

Comment: Who's going to know if you "forge" it? The validator's results are between you and the computer running the validation software.

Comment: You have the ability to link the W3C valid image with the validation results.  Regardless, my question was answered.